# Is there a good reason why HTML doesn't have a shorthand method for closing a tag with content?

Tags: html, xml

I'm just curious.  Is there a reason why the "higher powers that be" have never added to the HTML spec (or XML specs, for that matter,) a shorthand method for closing tags that contain content?

For instance, lets say I have the following html table:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bar</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Is there any reason why a shorthand tag couldn't be used to close each tag?

Maybe something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>foo</><td>bar</><td>foo</></>
    <tr><td>bar</><td>foo</><td>bar</></>
    <tr><td>1</><td>2</><td>3</></>
</>
```

This could save a few bytes of data and the only downfall that I can see is that you can't quickly tell which tag (or tags) have been closed if they aren't given a named reference.  However, this could be a useful option if you are dynamically generating content and want to save a few bytes in your data.

I'm positive I'm not the first person to think of this.  Why hasn't such functionality been added to any HTML or XML specification?

Comment: Which is better: `</p></blockquote></div></section></article></div></body></html>` or `</></></></></></></></>`?

Comment: BoltClock: For readability, certainly option #1.  However, if you are generating content, and you are using a framework to output your HTML, then option #2 is better.  The framework could have a "debug" option to write closing tags for development.  Once an application has finished being tested, you could toggle a debugger setting to write simplified closing tags.  Those would save bytes in the data.  Is that ever a bad thing?

Comment: What if I drop the first `</>`? Should the browser try to close the `<p>` or the `<div>` with the first `</>`?

Comment: @RLH If you're generating content, you have all the freedom to use [Content-Coding: gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression#Content-coding_tokens) which will compress closing tags _incredibly_ efficently.

Comment: lanzz: That would be nice but that's not an option.  See my comments to James Allardice's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML, as defined by specifications up and including HTML 4.01, does have shorthand methods for closing elements with content. This is just theoretical, but the question is really why *browsers did not implement* such features. The features are mentioned, among other things, in HTML 4.01 spec in [B.3.7 Shorthand markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.7), and they include NET (= Null End Tag), e.g.

```
<blockquote/foobar/
```

which is by the formal definitions equivalent to

```
<blockquote>foobar</blockquote>
```

The spec says: “Documents that use them are conforming SGML documents, but are unlikely to work with many existing HTML tools.” This is an understatement in the sense that *no* browser ever implemented HTML by those specifications, i.e. as an SGML application (though some very rare browsers made some attempts at that direction). The issue is still reflected in HTML validation (in classic sense, excluding HTML5 validation, which plays by its own rules); see the [Saga of Slashed Validators](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/qattr.html).

So why didn’t browsers implement the specs in this respect? It would have been easy, in a sense, to take some existing SGML parser and include it into a browser. But the explanation is that browsers were written in ad hoc ways, fast and loose and pragmatically, paying little or no attention to issues like generalized markup. HTML specifications were written quite some time after first browsers, mostly standardizing existing practice but also throwing in some new principles. HTML was kind of retrofitted to SGML in the formal sense, but this was never taken seriously by browser vendors.

Comment: +1 for a much better explanation with regards to implementations (rather the lack thereof) and specifications.

Comment: Jukka gets the answer mark.  As he mentions, this is in the old HTML specs, which I was completely unaware of.  It's interesting that this has never been implemented in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

Historically, there were advocates of allowing abbreviated end tags in XML in the form `</>`, and in fact Microsoft allowed this in their first XML parser: see http://mailman.ic.ac.uk/pipermail/xml-dev/1998-April/003204.html

I can only speculate on why the final specification didn't allow this (and Microsoft pulled it from their products) - discovering the real reasons why a working group made a particular decision can be difficult even for those closely involved. But certainly there are arguments for and against; and the XML group seemed to value the benefits that come from redundancy more than the benefits that come from conciseness.

HTML is a different story, of course; they made quite different decisions about which subset of SGML to adopt.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly valid HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>My paragraph
</div>
```

If I were to replace the closing `</div>` tag with one of your short tags:

```
<div>
    <p>My paragraph
</>
```

How would the browser know whether you intended to close the `<p>` tag or the `<div>` tag? The main problem with this idea is that it introduces ambiguity, but obviously it also reduces readability and I'm sure others will come up with other negatives!

**Update**

Also note that since you should be serving pages with gzip compression (which works by finding repeated characters in text) you could actually *harm* over-the-wire transfer sizes by doing this. A very quick test at http://gzipper.com confirmed that for a small text:

```
<div><div><div><div><div></div></div></div></div></div> <!-- 45% compression -->
<div><div><div><div><div></></></></></> <!-- 25% compression -->
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that and I see your point. However, there is nothing saying that it couldn't be written in the spec to always close the last, open tag whenever the shorthand closing tag is present. This would mean that you would need to end your example with "</></>", which is only one character larger than the original. In many cases you could still save quite a few bytes using a shorthand tag. (Is this better BoltClock?)

Comment: Actually, I'm not serving pages with gzip.  In my case I have a very simple, embedded web server.  The API for the web server doesn't include GZIP functionality and including such a library would use up valuable resources on our simplistic device.

Comment: @RLH - Well I guess the focus was on structure and readability rather than character counts. To be honest, I think I'd rather it be the way it is than have the potential ambiguity and extra cost to maintenance and development times. If you have real concerns over the weight of your pages, I suggest you implement as many of [these points](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) as you can.

Comment: Furthermore, having such a shorthand would be nice because I'm going through an exercise right now of trying to shave off as many bytes as possible from within our current project HTML assets.  This exercise is what has had me "wishing" that there was away to shorthand close all of my tags.  I can't compress my outputted content but I could trim down 10% of the size of all of my HTML files if there was a way to shorthand close all of these damned HTML tags.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is *loosely permissible* to use gems such as `<b>foo <i>bar</b> baz</i>` (not correct per se, but it is interpreted correctly by (some?) browsers).
2. Optional closing tags, described in @JamesAllardice's answer.
3. Catching nesting errors is (marginally) easier with descriptive closing tags; remember, your closing tag might be several screens away from its opening tag.
4. The "powers that be" are much more concerned with backwards compatibility than with shaving 1-2% off HTML pages in this era of widespread broadband.
5. The "powers that be" usually operate on *decade-long* cycles in standards development; it is *very hard* for *anything* to happen there.

Answer (score 1):

The irony here is that although not general, the specific example you give of table markup can be written even shorter, both validly and with full support in browsers, by simply dropping most of the end tags completely, like this:

```
<table><tr>
  <td>foo<td>bar<td>foo<tr>
  <td>bar<td>foo<td>bar<tr>
  <td>1<td>2<td>3</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what tags you are talking about.
For Example:

```
Break-Line: <br/>
Link: <link />
Input: <input />
Img: <img />
```

These could be considered short-hand.

I do agree with you. For example when you are programming in another language and create a block of code and are only using brackets it knows which bracket closes a block of code.

Maybe in the future they will do something similar.

Comment: He's not referring to self-closing tags or void elements. He's referring to a shorthand way of specifying end tags.

Comment: I know I was just trying to give him some valid input, because I know where he is coming from. Its like when you are programming a function. Function() { } why cant it be more like that. I guess the short answer should have been No you cant and left out my example, because it was not that relevant. I apologize.